# What is the difference between Kali Linux minimal and normal?

Tags: kali-linux

Generally the minimal versions of distros come with a fewer selection of packages. Is this the same for Kali Linux minimal? What packages will be missing from the minimal installation? Is there a site where the packages are listed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most GNU/Linux Distros have a "mini" version so the end user can download the OS faster then their respective "full" counterparts.

You may end up downloading more than you need in many cases.

There many motivations for creating a "mini" version of a distro:

- Download image in short amount of time
- Starting system install in shorter amount of time
- Only install the minimal software necessary
- Use network on-demand, instead of upfront

After reading the documentation of Kali Linux, it seems they do so for the same reason:

> The Kali mini ISO is a convenient way to install a minimal Kali system and install it “from scratch”. The mini install ISO will download all required packages from our repositories, meaning you need to have a fast Internet connection to use this installation method.

This entails the use of your bandwith on-demand instead of upfront.

Source can be viewed here: [Kali Linux Mini ISO Install](http://docs.kali.org/network-install/kali-linux-network-mini-iso-install)