# Difference between Kali Linux 2.0 mini and Light

Tags: kali-linux

Recently [Kali Linux 2.0](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) is released and they release Normal,Minimal and Light ISO installations. Minimal Kali Linux installations has necessary software packages and some other motivations.[Some of them are listed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107110/what-is-the-difference-between-kali-linux-minimal-and-normal). But what is Light installation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [mini ISO](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-network-mini-iso-install) only provides the minimum necessary to boot Kali and allow installation over the Internet; that's why it's so small. The normal ISO provides the full Kali 2.0 setup using GNOME 3, which now requires 768MB of memory. The [light ISO](https://www.kali.org/releases/kali-linux-20-released/) provides a Kali 2.0 setup using XFCE, and a smaller selection of tools (Iceweasel, OpenSSH, NMap, NCrack, SQLMap and AirCrack-NG; see [`variant-light/package-lists/kali.list.chroot` in the live build configuration](http://git.kali.org/gitweb/?p=live-build-config.git;a=blob;f=kali-config/variant-light/package-lists/kali.list.chroot;h=5dfc12ba6c75f3e6bfd0983da6ac702372f06c8e;hb=HEAD) for details).